# Rails - Help for design: application with different user privilege levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, privileges

This is my first question on stackoverflow, it is quite generic, hope I can get suggestions here.

I quickly made a Rails3 administrative-only application, mostly used for data-entry tasks about heating plants maintenance. It consists of about 10 models and I widely used scaffolding and resource nesting to build up a single full privileged user (admin) application. Mainly there is a system model, with many child models, and each system belongs to an operator.

Now I need each operator to login and manage his own systems, - almost - exactly how the admin user can do, but restricting privileges to systems that belongs to that operator.

Now the question... Should I:

**(1) Filter data in the model's scaffold generated controllers?**

E.g. (don't care about syntax, just to give the idea):

```
def index
  if session[:operator_id]
    @operator = operators.find(session[:operator_id])
    @systems = @operator.systems
  else if session[:admin] == true
    @systems = System.all
  end
end
```

**(2) Write different controllers for operators restricting privileges?**

Replacing the scaffold-generated structure with one folder for admin's controllers with e.g. System.all statements, and a second one for operators' controllers with e.g. @operator.systems statements.

**(3) Split in separate applications?**

To save the scaffold-generated structure? You are saying NO!NO!NO!, right?

**(4) Hope to get a better suggestion from stackoverflow expert users?**

Thank you all...

Answer (score 0):

From performance point of view filtering rows by operator like you showed in 1 is best.

For security reasons you should also do checking in before_filter of you controllers, so operator 1 can't view others operator data. For example if system 1 belongs to operator 1 you need to make sure that operator 2 can't type in browser systems/1 and view data (assuming system/1 is :controller => :system, :action => :show, :id => 1)

If performance isn't big issue you can take a look at [Authorization plugin](https://github.com/DocSavage/rails-authorization-plugin), it allows role based object instance authorization with cool syntax for checking rights :)

Comment: Thank you Adrian, of course there will be a before_filter to authenticate operators by entering user and password. Then all data will be filtered by fetching data only through the operator object, look above: @systems = @operator.find(session[:operator_id]).systems. Yeah, you're right, even other actions must have similar filters. Maybe a even a before_filter with redirection should be nice. I am concerned about maintainability of the code rather than performance. Is still the first idea the best one? Of course I'll take a look to the plugin you mentioned.